# Calculating distribution function exponential distribution

Tags: integration, random-variables

I have a question about the following example of a continuous random variable:

> If $X$ has the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then
>
> $ F_X(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0& \text{if }x\leq 0,\\
> 1-e^{-\lambda x}& \text{if }x>0,
> \end{cases}$
>
> with density function
>
> $f_x(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0& \text{if }x\leq 0\\
> \lambda e^{-\lambda x}& \text{if }x>0.
> \end{cases}$

Now, my textbook provides us with the following definition of **continuous** random variables:

> A random variable $X$ is **continuous** if its distribution function $F_X$ may be written in the form
>
> $F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)\text{d}u\quad \text{for } x\in \mathbb R$,
>
> for some non-negative function $f_X$.

So, I tried to write out $F_X(x)$ for some value $x<0$. What we'd get is:

\begin{align}
F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)\text{d}u=&\int_{-\infty}^{0}f_X(u)\text{d}u + \int_{0}^{x}f_X(u)\text{d}u\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^{0}0\text{d}u+\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{a}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\text{d}u\\
=&\int_{0}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\text{d}u= \left[-e^{-\lambda x}\right]_{o}^{x}=-e^{-\lambda x}.
\end{align}

But how can I get '1'? I understand this is an integration constant, but as far as I know, integration constants are only involved in indefinite integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-0} = 1
$$
or more specifically
$$
\left[-\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} \right]_0^x=-\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} - (-1) = 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} 
$$

Comment: Oh, I was so stupid. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A side note: You have mixed up $x$ and $u$. $f_X(u)$ must be written in terms of  $u$, because $u$ is the integration variable. $x$ is the upper bound.

$$\int_{0}^{x}f_X(u)\, \text{d}u=\int_{0}^{x}\lambda e^{-\lambda \color{red} u}\, \text{d}u$$ $$=\left[ -e^{-\lambda \color{red} u}  \right]_0^x=-e^{-\lambda  x}-(-e^{-\lambda \cdot 0})=-e^{-\lambda  x}+1=1-e^{-\lambda  x}$$

Comment: Thanks!:) That is indeed something I tend to forget.

Comment: @ShaVuklia You are welcome. There is a good chance that you will not forget it again in the future.